# ClientScript is not triggered when running page from an External URL

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am running a simple suitelet with a form, to which I am adding a clientscript.

```
form.clientScriptModulePath = './clientScript.js';
```

It works fine, as long as the suitlet is run from the 'normal' url.
But if External URL is used, clientScript seems to be completely ignored, no error, just ignored.

[image]

Are Client Scripts not available for External URL's in NetSuite? Or is there some workaround for it?

I didn't find any documentations for External URL restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select Available Without Login and then save the Script Deployment record, an External URL
field is displayed on the Script Deployment page (see following figure). Use this URL for Suitelets you want
to make available to users who do not have an active NetSuite session.

*Note* **The Website feature must be enabled for Clients Scripts to work in externally available Suitelets**

Please go to Set up > company > Enable features >Web presence > Website.
Here is a screenshot for your reference

[image: enable the feature in NetSuite>]

The Suitelet should be in released status to avoid any other errors.

The following table shows how you can specify the localization context based on the script type.

| Script Type | Defining Localization Context Filtering |
| --- | --- |
| SuiteScript 2.0 Client Script Type | Complete the following steps to add localization context filtering to client scripts:1. Use the localizationContextEnter and localizationContextExit entry points in your script. |

Please let me know how this goes!! Happy coding :)

Comment: I have a suitelet setup as an external url, and I am using it as such. (released status is also set), i don't follow what do you mean by : "The Website feature must be enabled for Clients Scripts to work in externally available Suitelets"

Comment: I have edited my answer to add what I mean by enabling the Website feature in NetSuite. Please try this and let me know how this goes!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but I think your clientScriptModule path needs to be absolute for it to work externally. I think I ran into this a couple of years ago and that turned out to be the solution.